# How to make a button or label above a CALayer in Xcode?

Tags: ios, core-graphics

In my storyboard I added a button & a label. In my ViewController I programmatically defined a CALayer and added it as a sublayer to the ViewController's view. When I test the app the sublayer is above the button and the label but I want to make the sublayer below the button and the label.

here's the code

.h file

```
// The CALayer declaration
CALayer *graphic;
```

.m file

```
//The screen width and height
CGRect screenBound = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGSize screenSize = screenBound.size;
CGFloat screenWidth = screenSize.width;
CGFloat screenHeight = screenSize.height;

//The CALayer definition
graphic = [CALayer layer];
graphic.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, screenHeight, screenWidth);
graphic.position = CGPointMake(screenHeight/2, screenWidth/2);
graphic.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
graphic.opacity = 0.1f;
[self.view.layer addSublayer:graphic];
```

How can I make the sublayer (graphic) appear below the button and label?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Only use the [tag:xcode] tag for questions about the IDE itself. Thanks!

Comment: `[ self.view.layer insertSublayer:graphic below:self.button.layer ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can do is to add your button and label programmatically to your layer.

**EDIT**

Ok, I figured out what the problem was. When you added this line: `[graphic addSublayer:self.btn.layer];` your application was crashing because your button was already added to the view hierarchy because you were creating it using a Storyboard.

What I did was to declare a new label and button without adding it to the storyboard (see comment "A"). After that I instantiated them inside method `viewDidLoad` and then added them to the layer you created.

**WARNING**

This code I'm showing here will effectively display your label and button on top of the `CALayer` however keep in mind that `CALayer`s are used for drawing and animation, not for user interaction. Unlike a `UIView` a `CALayer` doesn't inherit from `UIResponder` and for this reason it cannot receive the touches a `UIView` receives.

However, there's a workaround. Instead of using Target-Action mechanism you can use Gesture Recognizers to be able to detect touches and interaction from the user. In this example I added a simple `UITapGestureRecognizer` to illustrate how it's done. Every time you tap on the button a "Button Tapped" message will be displayed in the console.

```
// This is the *.m file
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

// Comment A. Another label and button added to the class without adding them to the
// storyboard
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *firstButton;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *mylabel;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.firstButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [self.firstButton setTitle:@"Just a Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    self.firstButton.frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, 300, 40);
    UIGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(theAction:)];
    [self.firstButton addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];

    self.mylabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 120, 200, 40)];
    self.mylabel.text = @"Hello World";
    self.mylabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor cyanColor];

    //The screen width and height
    CGRect screenBound = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGSize screenSize = screenBound.size;
    CGFloat screenWidth = screenSize.width;
    CGFloat screenHeight = screenSize.height;

    //The CALayer definition
    CALayer *graphic = nil;
    graphic = [CALayer layer];
    graphic.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, screenHeight, screenWidth);
    graphic.position = CGPointMake(screenHeight/2, screenWidth/2);
    graphic.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    graphic.opacity = 1.0f;
    [graphic addSublayer:self.firstButton.layer];
    [graphic addSublayer:self.mylabel.layer];
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:graphic];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)theAction:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"Button Tapped");
}
@end
```

Let me know if you have more questions.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry, But this is not working. I replaced the .button with ->button the app was paused

Comment: How did you declare your button? Can you show your entire class?

Comment: What do you mean by the entire class?

Comment: I mean what you have in your *.h and *.m files

Comment: The code I wrote above only plus the IBOutlet of the button and the label in .h file

Comment: If you have declared your button as an IBOutlet (and assuming it is correctly connected) then you should access it using the dot "." operator and not the arrow "->" operator. Also what method is the code you posted in?

Comment: I just pressed ctrl and dragged the button into the .h file

Comment: What's the name of your button variable?

Comment: @AFapps, please see my updated answer. Use: `[graphic addSublayer:self.btn.layer];`

Comment: Please post all the code of your class so I can test it on my end

Comment: I uploaded the projects in dropbox here is the link
https://www.dropbox.com/s/wo72ef5j5almzey/BtnOverCALayer.zip

Comment: Awesome, I'll take a look

Comment: Thank you! But I don't understand why the button is not responding to the action.

Comment: Because `UIView`s handle user interaction and `CALayer`s don't. If you look at the class hierarchy of both classes you'll see that `UIView` inherits from `UIResponder` but `CALayer` doesn't. That's why it can't receive any actions from the user. The workaround is to attach a `UIGestureRecognizer` to it and that will do the trick. Just like in the example I gave you. You may want to also take a look at this link: http://raptureinvenice.com/ios-brownbag-view-vs-layers-including-clock-demo/