# how to add buttons on CALayer in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uibutton, calayer

How to add `UIButtons` , `UILabels` `UIImageView` on `CALayer` and perform actions according to the button pressed.Thanks in advance

```
 {
   [graphic addSublayer:self.firstButton.layer];
   [graphic addSublayer:self.mylabel.layer];
   [self.view.layer addSublayer:graphic];
 }
```

I used the above code but when I pressed the button it does not perform any action 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A CALayer is not an event responder, If you want a button that actually works on top of a CALayer, put that CALayer into a UIView and add a UIButton to that view.

Comment: It gives an warning as Incompaitable pointer types sending CALayer to parameter of type UIView

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/2502/calayers-tutorial-for-ios-introduction-to-calayers-tutorial follow this tutorial

Comment: Yeah, that's correct. But you can add tap gesture on UIButton and it will detect. [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19456916/4061501), NB: I'm not checked by code.